# Why spring transaction roll back does not delete the data inserted into database?

Tags: spring, transactions, rollback

I defined a transactional function in service, and call it from a scheduled task, in this function, I performed two round of insert into database for same object, which will throw exception during second round of insert because of duplicated key. I have configured the transactional annotation to rollback for the exception thrown out, and I opened the log4j springframework log, from the log I can see that the transaction manager is doing something with the rollback like determining whether to rollback for the exception thrown out, but I cannot see any log that is doing some database delete operation, and checking the database shows that the rollback does not delete the record inserted in the first round of insert.

I searched a lot for the not rolling back issue, mostly it's caused because not defining the exception for rollback, but in my case I have it defined. Another popular reason is that doing internal calling of the transactional method, but in my case, first I am using aspectj config, second I am calling the transactional method from another class which is a scheduler.

So please anybody provide some help on my case why it's not working?????

Following is my code and configuration and logs. I am using spring 3.x and mybatis and mysql. 
====== application context config=======

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="mysqldataSource" /> 
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />
```

=======transactional method==============

```
    @Transactional (rollbackFor = {Exception.class,MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class,DuplicateKeyException.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testTransaction()
```

=======logs from spring framework=========

2014-12-18 13:40:04.747 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:140) -DEBUG   Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6921ddb6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@52ffe2cb] bound to thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:40:04.963 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:140) -DEBUG   Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6921ddb6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@52ffe2cb] bound to thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:40:04.965 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] [taskScheduler-1] (SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:217) -DEBUG   Database product name cached for DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@52ffe2cb]: name is 'MySQL'
2014-12-18 13:40:04.975 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory] [taskScheduler-1] (SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:175) -DEBUG   SQL error codes for 'MySQL' found
2014-12-18 13:40:04.978 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] [taskScheduler-1] (SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:403) -DEBUG   Translating SQLException with SQL state '23000', error code '1062', message [Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY']; SQL was [] for task [

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

#### The error may involve org.sample.dao.mapper.ComplaintCCMapper.insert-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: insert into cc_complaint_info (complaint_id,cell_phone,IMSI,cell_brand,cell_model,network_type,fault_time,fault_city,fault_location_latitude,fault_location_longitude,fault_type,possible_reason,recommend_answer,refd_recovertime,satisfaction,workorder_id)   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

]
2014-12-18 13:43:10.776 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] [taskScheduler-1] (RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:148) -DEBUG   Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException]
2014-12-18 13:43:10.785 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:851) -DEBUG   Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
2014-12-18 13:43:10.791 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:294) -DEBUG   Setting JDBC transaction [jdbc:mysql://147.128.123.40:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=root@147.128.124.35, MySQL Connector Java] rollback-only
2014-12-18 13:43:52.874 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionAspectSupport.java:488) -DEBUG   Completing transaction for [org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl.testTransaction] after exception: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

#### The error may involve org.sample.dao.mapper.ComplaintCCMapper.insert-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: insert into cc_complaint_info (complaint_id,cell_phone,IMSI,cell_brand,cell_model,network_type,fault_time,fault_city,fault_location_latitude,fault_location_longitude,fault_type,possible_reason,recommend_answer,refd_recovertime,satisfaction,workorder_id)   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

; SQL []; Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'
2014-12-18 13:43:52.875 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] [taskScheduler-1] (RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:131) -DEBUG   Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

#### The error may involve org.sample.dao.mapper.ComplaintCCMapper.insert-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: insert into cc_complaint_info (complaint_id,cell_phone,IMSI,cell_brand,cell_model,network_type,fault_time,fault_city,fault_location_latitude,fault_location_longitude,fault_type,possible_reason,recommend_answer,refd_recovertime,satisfaction,workorder_id)   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

; SQL []; Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'
2014-12-18 13:43:52.876 [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] [taskScheduler-1] (RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.java:148) -DEBUG   Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.876 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936) -DEBUG   Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2014-12-18 13:43:52.877 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:243) -DEBUG   Removed value [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionHolder@5d1b84d6] for key [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory@7337842f] from thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.878 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:140) -DEBUG   Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6921ddb6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@52ffe2cb] bound to thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.879 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:243) -DEBUG   Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6921ddb6] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@52ffe2cb] from thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.880 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) -DEBUG   Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2014-12-18 13:43:52.889 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844) -DEBUG   Initiating transaction rollback
2014-12-18 13:43:52.893 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:280) -DEBUG   Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://147.128.123.40:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=root@147.128.124.35, MySQL Connector Java]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.897 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:965) -DEBUG   Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2014-12-18 13:43:52.898 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:331) -DEBUG   Clearing transaction synchronization
2014-12-18 13:43:52.899 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:243) -DEBUG   Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@59f82fa3] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@631298f5] from thread [taskScheduler-1]
2014-12-18 13:43:52.906 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:323) -DEBUG   Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://147.128.123.40:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=root@147.128.124.35, MySQL Connector Java] after transaction
2014-12-18 13:43:52.906 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) -DEBUG   Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2014-12-18 13:43:52.906 [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] [taskScheduler-1] (TaskUtils.java:95) -ERROR   Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

#### The error may involve org.sample.dao.mapper.ComplaintCCMapper.insert-Inline

#### The error occurred while setting parameters

#### SQL: insert into cc_complaint_info (complaint_id,cell_phone,IMSI,cell_brand,cell_model,network_type,fault_time,fault_city,fault_location_latitude,fault_location_longitude,fault_type,possible_reason,recommend_answer,refd_recovertime,satisfaction,workorder_id)   values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

#### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'

; SQL []; Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:371)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:240)
    at org.sample.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.insert(BaseDaoImpl.java:53)
    at org.sample.service.impl.BaseServiceImpl.insert(BaseServiceImpl.java:27)
    at org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl.testTransaction_aroundBody0(testTransactionImpl.java:55)
    at org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl$AjcClosure1.run(testTransactionImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl.testTransaction(testTransactionImpl.java:21)
    at org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7a27ce95.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at org.sample.service.impl.testTransactionImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4e5770f7.testTransaction()
    at org.sample.Util.ScheduleTest.testTransaction(ScheduleTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:64)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '20141218013806914313591877775' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1049)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1302)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:69)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
    ... 35 more

Comment: BTW: MY mysql is having innodb engine supporting rollback

Answer (score 0):

OK  I think I found out a way to fix it although I dont know the real root cause. I still want to post it out in case anybody else has the similar issue. the discussion in this link give me some hint :http://www.coderanch.com/t/590731/Spring/Spring-Transaction-Rollback
in this discussion, the asker found two "Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource" operations in the log, so I checked my log, and also found two lines of "Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource" before and after initiating the roll back.

> 2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) -DEBUG   Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844) -DEBUG   Initiating transaction rollback
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:280) -DEBUG   Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://147.128.123.40:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=root@147.128.124.35, MySQL Connector Java]
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:965) -DEBUG   Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:331) -DEBUG   Clearing transaction synchronization
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.321 [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] [taskScheduler-1] (TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:243) -DEBUG   Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@f3e84eb] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@4bd122b8] from thread [taskScheduler-1]
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.352 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceTransactionManager.java:323) -DEBUG   Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://147.128.123.40:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8, UserName=root@147.128.124.35, MySQL Connector Java] after transaction
>   2014-12-18 14:59:43.352 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] [taskScheduler-1] (DataSourceUtils.java:327) -DEBUG   Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

So I checked my project and found two applicationContext*.xml, both having transaction manager configured, I remove duplicate config from another applicationContext4Test.xml and run again, the roll back work now!!!!
and when the transaction works, I can see from the debugging that the transaction manager just hold the commit to database until the method finish without exception, this explains to me how the transaction is working in spring..... which I cannot understand before "how can transaction manager knows how to delete the record I inserted in to database when exception happens" stupid question huh!